# iOS what to use for a sorted list?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been looking at the iOS collection classes and am trying to find a SortedList.

I would like to have a custom Comparer method that compares two objects, similar to the .NET SortedList class.

I do not want to sort the list myself every time I need it sorted, I was hoping to find a class that I could pass a compare method two and every time I add/insert an object it gets inserted into the correct location so the list is always sorted.

Sorry if this is a foolish question, but there are many different collection classes in iOS.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Make a list and sort it.  NSArray/NSMutableArray is the standard list, and it has a number of different sort options.

Answer (score 3):

Foundation has no mutable collection class that keeps a list sorted.

Use `NSMutableArray` and its `-insertObject:atIndex:` to add objects. Determine the correct index by using `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`.

From the NSArray reference:

> If the NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex option is specified, returns the index at which you should insert obj in order to maintain a sorted array:
>
> - If the obj is found and neither NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual nor NSBinarySearchingLastEqual is specified,
>     returns any equal or one larger index than any matching object’s
>     index.
> - [...]
> - If the object is not found, returns
>     the index of the least greater object, or the index at the end of the
>     array if the object is larger than all other elements.
>
> **Special Considerations:** The elements in the array must have already been sorted
>   using the comparator cmp. If the array is not sorted, the result is
>   undefined.

Your category method could look like this:

```
- (void)ymy_insertSortedObject:(id)obj
{
    NSUInteger insertionIndex = [self indexOfObject:obj
                                      inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)
                                            options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                                    usingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
    }];
}
```

- Reference: [-[NSArray indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:) (since iOS 4, OS X 10.6)
- General Foundation collection best practices: [objc.io issue #7](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html)

**EDIT:** Here's a drop-in category you can use: [NSMutableArray+YMYSorted.h](https://gist.github.com/yangmeyer/61536e849943423ea67a#file-nsmutablearray-ymysorted-m)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSMutableArray`. Its sort method is highly optimised for the case that the array is already mostly sorted. It's also highly optimised for the case that the array is already sorted in reverse order, or for sorting an array that was created by concatenating two sorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

NSarray or NSMutableArray are likely the storage types you would like to use, as they have the most easily sorted internal structure.

You should then look into the sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) method.

Comment: Note that an NSMutableArray allows insertions and deletions, and it's a relatively modest programming job to write a little bit of code (could even be a "category" on NSMutableArray) to insert a new value at the proper location, using binary search.

Comment: Yes, and it is much more efficient to maintain a sorted structure then resort repeatedly.

Comment: Depending on the number of objects in your array and the response time needed, resorting each time may be fine. It's a no-code solution if you don't have a lot of items to sort, or if you're not shaving off milliseconds to get UI responsiveness. Measure first if need be. Premature optimization is the root of all evil....

Comment: LOL, ok, so my assumption was correct and the answer is no, there is nothing like the SortedList Class in .net c#.  So I supposed, yes, I can use a NSMutableArray, and my data set is fairly small so I can sort it when needed and it wont be so bad.  Thank everyone for the replies.  BTW, one of the places I need to use it is in a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code in order to achieve a sorted array: -

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {



 if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {

      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;

 }



 if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {

      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;

 }

 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;

}];
```